# Increased space between items on the website

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, html

Good day!
I'm making a layout site and I am having the following problem:

There is a page on which some data is dynamically loaded. When the initial page is loaded, the item cannot be displayed accurately.
[before ajax update](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vlen5fdvs5r1nud/before%20ajax%20update.PNG?dl=0)

After updating the data item is displayed as it should.
[after ajax update](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9feuhrhu2n2oh18/after%20ajax%20update.PNG?dl=0)

What needs to be done to the original page looked neat.

*Thank you.*

HTML:

```
<table id="loco-summary" class="no-loco">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="selection" style="background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.35)">Подключено: 26</span>
                <span class="selection" style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.35)">Отключено на станции: 10</span>
                <span class="selection" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)">Отключено: 20</span>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2" class="border-left" style="white-space: nowrap;">
                <span class="selection">Всего: 67</span>
                <span class="error-selection" style="background-color: white; color: red;">Ошибки: 15</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="selection">На станции: 32</span>
                <span class="selection">В депо: 7</span>
                <span class="selection">Вне станции: 28</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you have any markup you can show?

Comment: It's good in my Chrome browser.

Comment: is your problem solved or not??

Comment: Remove all spaces before & after `span` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with white space in the initial markup. The white space is not there in the markup returned by your ajax call.

Executing this

```
$("#loco-summary tbody").css("white-space", "nowrap");
```

in the console seems to fix the problem, so id suggest either remove all the white-space in the loco-summary table, or set the white-space using css.

Answer (score 0):

you should not use inline styles, but i am adapting to your coding style.

change your table to the following:

i've added a width to your table

```
<table id="loco-summary" class="small" style="width: 400px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="selection" style="background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.35)">Подключено: 26</span>
                <span class="selection" style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.35)">Отключено на станции: 10</span>
                <span class="selection" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)">Отключено: 20</span>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2" class="border-left" style="white-space: nowrap;">
                <span class="selection">Всего: 67</span>
                <span class="error-selection" style="background-color: white; color: red;">Ошибки: 15</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="selection">На станции: 32</span>
                <span class="selection">В депо: 7</span>
                <span class="selection">Вне станции: 28</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```